# SOA bpel pick activity on alarm branch externalize the timeout

Tags: configuration, timeout, soa, bpel

I am using Pick activity in my bpel process which has on message and on alarm branch . I currently have set it in my code as OnAlarm for 30 secs. 
But is there any way to externalize the property in the config plan?? So that i can change it  during deployment using config plan and do not have to change it in the code. (something similar to ora:getpreference which we used for externalizing other properties)

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like you have noticed, you can use ora:getPreference to achieve it. Configure it to use "for Expression in XPATH 1.0" and in expression field simply type ora:getPreference(yourComponentPreferenceName). Just remember to add bpel.preference.yourComponentPreferenceName property to your component definition in composite.xml. Remember that the value you provide must be in xsd:duration format. Generate new config plan and you should see your new property.